# List from nested predicates

Tags: prolog

I want to know if it's possible to get a list of numbers from nested predicates in prolog.

I'll make an example, from:

```
?- elements(p(f(0,5,1), k(8, f(7,3), h(6)), 5), X).
```

I want in X this:

```
X = [0,5,1,8,7,3,6,5].
```

Thank you if you can help me =)

Comment: Yes, it is. Is that all you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Prolog has append/2 and maplist/3:

```
elements(N, [N]) :- number(N), !.
elements(S, Ss) :- S=..[_|Es], maplist(elements, Es, Ts), append(Ts, Ss).
```

Comment: It Worked! ok.... now let me try to explain this method.
if the predicate is a number then the searched list is the list containing only that number (case 1).
if not, then decompose the predicate, take the tail, apply elements on the tail and put the result in Ts. Then Ts is appended to the output list.

I was doing something similar but the idea to explicitly use the tail wit [_Es] is great! Thank you!! =)

Comment: Non-relational: `X=[2], elements(X,[2]).` succeeds, but `elements(X,[2]), X=[2].` fails. In case you cannot produce all answers, an instantiation error is called for!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you write predicates involving general term traversal, always keep in mind that such predicates will be limited in the way they can be used. Let's call your relation `term_subtermnumbers/2` which relates a term to the list of numbers that occur in it as subterms in the order of their left-to-right appearance, including multiple occurrences. First, you may think of examples you gave, like

```
?- term_subtermnumbers(p(f(0,5,1), k(8, f(7,3), h(6)), 5), Numbers).
   Numbers = [0, 5, 1, 8, 7, 3, 6, 5].
```

But what if you turn the query around, and ask instead:

```
?- term_subtermnumbers(Term, [0, 5, 1, 8, 7, 3, 6, 5]).
```

There are many possibilities for solutions. In fact, infinitely many. Or take a simpler query:

```
?- term_subtermnumbers(Term, []).
```

That is, all the `Term`s that do not contain numbers.

Since the set of solutions is infinite here, and there is no way to abbreviate that set meaningfully as answers, it really makes sense to produce in that case a special error called an **instantiation error**.

Some - not all - Prolog built-ins ensure this property. `(=..)/2` and `functor/3` are faithfully guaranteeing that property. Helas, `number/1` is not. As a consequence, always use `(=..)/2` or `functor/3` prior to `number/1`, `atom/1`, `atomic/1` and some others.

```
term_subtermnumbers(Term, Numbers) :-
  phrase(subtermnumbers(Term), Numbers).

subtermnumbers(Term) -->
   { Term =.. [_| Args] },
   ( {number(Term)} -> [Term]
   ; args_subtermnumbers(Args)
   ).

args_subtermnumbers([]) --> [].
args_subtermnumbers([Arg|Args]) -->
   subtermnumbers(Arg),
   args_subtermnumbers(Args).
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
?- elements(p(f(0,5,1), k(8, f(7,3), h(6)), 5), X), writenl(X), fail.

elements(X,X) :- integer(X).
elements([],[]).
elements([X|Y],Z) :- integer(X), elements(Y,V), Z=[X|V].
elements([X|Y],Z) :- elements(X,W), elements(Y,V), append(W,V,Z).
elements(_(|Y),Z) :- elements(Y,Z).

writenl(X) :- write(X), nl.
```

It gave me `[0, 5, 1, 8, 7, 3, 6, 5]`.

---

Try this instead:

```
?- elements(p(f(0,5,1), k(8, f(7,3), h(6)), 5), X), writenl(X), fail.

elements(X,X) :- integer(X).
elements([],[]).
elements([X|Y],Z) :- integer(X), elements(Y,V), Z=[X|V].
elements([X|Y],Z) :- elements(X,W), elements(Y,V), append(W,V,Z).
elements(X,Z) :- X=..[_|Y], elements(Y,Z).

writenl(X) :- write(X), nl.
```

Comment: =( it gives me a syntax error with 
    "elements(_(|Y),Z) :- elements(Y,Z)."

Comment: @D.C - Strawberry Prolog has a few syntax variations. I've posted a different version.

Comment: `elements([], Xs).` produces infinitely many answers `Xs = []`.